# Java generics: Checking type when the variable is null

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a problem handling possible values of a generic type. I want to have a TimeTreeNodeDTO that should be able to handle two types of TimeTrees. A timetree with int values and timetree with double value. To do that I added a generic T (extending of Number to handle both Interger and Double without problems).

```
public class TimeTreeNodeDTO<T extends Number>
{

    // ....

    private T value;

    private List<TimeTreeNodeDTO<T>> children;

    public TimeTreeNodeDTO(PeriodType periodType, List<TimeTreeNodeDTO<T>> children) {
        this.periodType = periodType;
        this.value = calculateValue(children);
        this.children = children;

    }

    private T calculateValue(List<TimeTreeNodeDTO<T>> children) {
        if(children == null || children.isEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (value instanceof Integer) {
            int sum = children.stream()
                    .mapToInt(node -> node.getValue().intValue())
                    .sum();
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(sum);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            double sum = children.stream()
                    .mapToDouble(node -> node.getValue().doubleValue())
                    .sum();
            return (T) Double.valueOf(sum);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type for value : " + value.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    // ....

}
```

So far I think is good (maybe there could be a better solution). And when I try to instance this happen

```
TimeTreeNodeDTO<Integer> wn1 = new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.WEEK, List.of(
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,1),
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,2),
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,3),
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,4),
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,5),
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,6),
                new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>(PeriodType.DAY,7)));
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at artelys.crystal.pdm.opus.timetreelib.dto.TimeTreeNodeDTO.calculateValue(TimeTreeNodeDTO.java:65)
    at artelys.crystal.pdm.opus.timetreelib.dto.TimeTreeNodeDTO.<init>(TimeTreeNodeDTO.java:33)
    at artelys.crystal.pdm.opus.timetreelib.TestTimeTreeDTO.setUp(TestTimeTreeDTO.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:76)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:506)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$21(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:491)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:168)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

I basically got a NullPointerException when running this line in TimeTreeNodeDTO class

`throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type for value : " + value.getClass().getName());`

This happen because **value** is null. I know is null, I'm suppose to calculate the value in this method, but because is not an Integer or a Double it goes directly to the else statement. Is there a way to check the type of the T value even if the value is null?

I tried to "initialize" the T value in 0 but I can't because is a generic. I don't know what else can I do.

I don't know maybe is a bad a approach and could be solved in another way.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: How can you expect to find the type of a null?

Comment: The thing is that when you declare a variable using generics you do something like this 

`TimeTreeNodeDTO<Integer> wn1 = new TimeTreeNodeDTO<>()`

So we are already defining the T type, even if the variable who is T is null. I want to check by example if the T type is an Integer (or not) inside the class and do something different in each case. I don't know if this is somehow possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely impossible; generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination. It exists to bind things together. For example, given this code:

```
public static Object nullCheck(Object o) {
  if (o == null) throw new NullPointerException();
  return o;
}

// to use:

class Example {
  private String name;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = nullCheck(name);
  }
}
```

By visual inspection and some very basic logic, this code, if somehow you were able to compile and run it, would run fine. However, this wouldn't compile - while **the code** guarantees that your `nullCheck` method either returns the same thing you gave it (so, that 'thing' is the same type as what you gave it), or throws, that's just in the code. Java, by design, assumes that code isn't write-once-and-never-change-it-ever-again. The **signatures** (the names, parameter types, return type, etcetera) are things you shouldn't change lightly (then all sorts of code needs to be recompiled), but you can change bodies just fine.

Hence why generics exists, to link things. This *does* work:

```
public static <T> T nullCheck(T o) {
  if (o == null) throw new NullPointerException();
  return o;
}
```

As a class file, the above would be **completely identical** to the earlier version, other than that the class file knows about the generics, but the JVM (`java.exe`) literally has no idea what generics are. It's like a comment to it.

Instead, what happens here is entirely a compile-time thing: The compiler does two things here:

- It knows that that the two Ts are linked: The type of the argument passed to `nullCheck` and the return type is the same type.
- Therefore it knows it can silently inject a cast; hence `this.name = nullCheck(name)` works because the compiler compiles that as if you wrote `this.name = (String) nullCheck(name)`.
- The compiler knows this 'guarantee' (that the arg and return type are the same) needs to be enforced; if you attempted to write the implementation of the `nullCheck` method such that the compiler cannot guarantee this, it would refuse to compile it.

But that is where it ends.

Those type parameters are not reified. The execution of `new ArrayList<String>()` and `new ArrayList<Integer>()` are **100% identical** - that arraylist has no idea what the generics are.

### Your bug

You're using `value` in your `calculateValue(List<..> children)` method. You're not supposed to; you are meant to use `child.value` (where child is some item from that list).

### Solutions

One really ugly solution you really do not want here, is that you pass `Class<T>` as part of the constructor of this thing, and thus now you know. This is really ugly - `j.l.Class` and generics don't quite cover the same ground: primitives can be represented as `j.l.Class` objects (`Class<?> x = int.class;` works fine), but generics cannot (`List<int> foo;` is a compiler error). Generics can nest (`List<Set<String>>` is fine), but that doesn't work in `j.l.Class` instances - those cannot carry generics, so you can't get any further than `Set.class` - you can't store the String part of that). Even if *here* you don't think you're going to run into it, having to pass the type explicitly means your caller have to repeat themselves which is nasty. Don't do that.

The better solution is simply not to report. You need another `else` on that big if clause batch in your code: if the `value` of a child isn't an Integer and also not a Double, but also not `null`, you can mention the type. If it is `null`, then it's not an issue of 'I do not support that type' - no, the issue is: 'somehow you managed to create a node whose value is `null` and that's not supported at all'.

Comment: Honestly, I would designate the "better solution" to be to just stick to a single numeric type and avoid generics.